# add code into icon Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have font icons and it work with class name and code, like this:

```
<i class="meh-icon icon-kids">&#xe87a;</i>
```

this is my code:

```
$items[1][] = array(
   'label' => $cat->name,
   'icon' => "meh-icon icon-" . $cat->icon . " icon-cat",
   'url' => aUrl('/discover/', array('section' => 'category', 'action' => $cat->url))
);
```

but it shows:

```
<i class="meh-icon icon-kids"></i>
```

I want add code into icon.

please help me.
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `'encodeLabel' => false` to your  items array